# ui-grid columnDefs error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a general purpose angular controller, which displays a grid view of data. I use it in multiple places of the page by providing different data.

I want to customize the column definition in html using `ng-init` like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="DataTableController" ng-init="setColDefs([{field:'c_partno', displayName:'Part No',width:'60px'}, {field:'c_owner',displayName:'Owner',width:'60px'}])">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="data-table"></div>
 </div>
```

However, I get 
**Error: Cannot parse column width '60px' for column named 'c_partno'**.

Very appreciated if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `width: 60` instead of `width: '60px'`
you can check this on the Documentation, hope it helps.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Defining-columns